# Count up with @each from a list with Sass

Tags: sass

I’m wondering if I can add a ‘counter’ with Sass when using the @each function. I have a list of backgrounds colors and I want to use the @each function to output a class name and a number behind it.

Is there a way with Sass to automatically count and add that into the class name?

```
$colors: blue, red, green;

@each $color in $colors {
  .class- {
    background: $color;
  }
}
```

So the output would be:

```
.class-1 {
 background: red
}

.class-2 {
 background: blue
}
```

Etc…

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
  .class-#{$i} {
      background: '#{nth($colors, $i)}';
  }
}
```